# Google Deployment Manager - Forwarding Rule (Error)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Help here would be much appreciated, this is something I have been struggling with for awhile. I am trying to deploy a VPN using the Google Deployment Manager. From what I understand I need the following:

```
VpnTargetGateway
ForwardingRules
VpnTunnels
ReservedIP
```

I am having trouble with the ForwardingRules. This is where I specify my already created reserved IP address and assign it to my target gateway. Here is my code:

```
resources: 
 - name: vmx-forwarding-rules
   type: compute.v1.forwardingRule
   properties:
     region: us-central1
     IPAddress: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{env["project"] }/regions/us-central1/addresses/vmx-ip
     IPProtocol: "ESP"
     target: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }/regions/us-central1/targetVpnGateways/vmx-vpn-gateway
```

Here is the error I receive:

`message: u"Unexpected response from resource of type compute.v1.forwardingRule: 400 {statusMessage=Bad Request, errors=[{message=Invalid value for field 'resource': ''.  A reserved IP should be specified for forwarding rule with target type TARGET_VPN_GATEWAY, domain=global, reason=invalid}]}">]>`

Does anyone have any experience with this or know a better location to find help for Deployment Manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your YAML configuration:

```
resources:
- name: vmx-ip
  type: compute.v1.address
  properties:
    region: us-central1

- name: vmx-forwarding-rules
  type: compute.v1.forwardingRule
  properties:
    region: us-central1
    IPAddress: $(ref.vmx-ip.address)
    IPProtocol: "ESP"
    target: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/regions/us-central1/targetVpnGateways/vmx-vpn-gateway
```

Comment: I am also deploying the reserved ip address via Google Cloud Deployment  Manager. How can I add address without finding and adding it manually. I'm trying to automate the Deployment of the VPN and reserved addresses are generated by Google.